# Como exibir 2 tabelas do BD dentro de um DataGridView na aplicação?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, winforms, datagridview

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida `C#` utilizando o projeto `Windows Forms` que exibe a Tabela Pessoas do Banco de Dados em uma lista no campo `DataGridView`. No entanto preciso exibir no `DataGridView` também a tabela `Endereco`.

**Observação:** *o relacionamento é 1 para 1*.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizo o código abaixo para ter o resultado conforme a print acima,

```
this.DataGridView1Pessoa.DataBindings.Add("DataSource",this, "ListPessoas"); 
this.DataGridView1Pessoa.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

e agora como faço para exibir Tabela `Endereco` e a Tabela pessoa no DataGridView, visto que já tentei adicionar a tabela `Endereco` utilizando o mesmo código citado acima, porém exibe a mensagem:

> "Isto gera duas associações na coleção para ligar à mesma propriedade. Nome do parâmetro: binding".

Tenho que exibir o resultado desse select abaixo no `dgv-DataGridView`.

> `"select * from Table_Pessoas left outer join Table_Endereco_Pessoa on Table_Endereco_Pessoa.Id_EnderecoPessoa = Table_Pessoas.Id_EnderecoPessoa left outer join Table_Endereco end_pessoa on end_pessoa.Id_Endereco = Table_Endereco_Pessoa.Id_Endereco"`

e para isso criei o método abaixo:

```
public SqlDataReader ListarPessoas()
{
        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand();
        query.CommandText = ("select * " +
                "from Table_Pessoas " +
                "left outer join Table_Endereco_Pessoa on Table_Endereco_Pessoa.Id_EnderecoPessoa = Table_Pessoas.Id_EnderecoPessoa " +
                "left outer join Table_Endereco end_pessoa on end_pessoa.Id_Endereco = Table_Endereco_Pessoa.Id_Endereco " +
                "left outer join Table_Orgao_Emissor_Rg on Table_Pessoas.Id_RgOrgEmiss = Table_Orgao_Emissor_Rg.Id_RgOrgEmiss");

        return (query.ExecuteReader());

}
```

Sei que para executar esse método preciso passar a propriedade "query.Connection" para fazer a conexão com o BD, porém já fiz varias pesquisas e não encontrei o que preciso fazer para fazer essa conexão funcionar na minha aplicação.

Para exibir a Tabela pessoa no dgv utilizo a conexão com bd através do arquivo app.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WindowsFormsApplication1Fams.Properties.Settings.FAMSConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-4KTTTDL\INSTANCEFAMS;Initial Catalog=BD_Fams;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="FamsContext" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-4KTTTDL\INSTANCEF;Initial Catalog=BD_F;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=f;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WindowsFormsApplication1Fams.Properties.Settings.FAMSConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-4KTTTDL\INSTANCEFAMS;Initial Catalog=BD_Fams;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="FamsContext" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-4KTTTDL\INSTANCEFAMS;Initial Catalog=BD_Fams;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=f@m5;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Utilizo a classe Table_Pessoa dentro da Pasta Data. Onde contém os Get e Set. 
E Utilizo uma classe PessoaModel dentro da Pasta Model. Conforme abaixo:

```
public class PessoaModel : DataContext<Table_Pessoas>
{
        public IEnumerable<Table_Pessoas> CarregarTodos()
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Table_Pessoas>(this.Context.Pessoas);
        }
}
```

E na classe do formulário. Carrego os dados do BD. Através do evento Load abaixo.

```
private IEnumerable<Table_Pessoas> listPessoa;
private void FrmCadastrarPessoa_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.ListPessoas = PessoaModel.CarregarTodos();
}
```

E nesta mesma classe no método abaixo para enfim passar os dados da Tabela Pessoa para o dgv.

```
public FrmCadastrarPessoa()
{
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataGridView1Pessoa.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", this, "ListPessoas");
       this.DataGridView1Pessoa.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
}
```

O problema agora é como implemento a propriedade `query.Connection` do meu método `ListarPessoas()` e exibo o retorno do mesmo no `dgv`?

Comment: Acho que a questão não é tanto suporta mais de uma tabela, mas sim se você fez o select e mapeamento corretamente, outra coisa seu relacionamento é 1 p/ 1 ou é 1 p/ muitos, se for o ultimo caso talvez seja melhor criar um DataGridView para abri com os dados do endereço de cada pessoa.

Comment: sendo uma tabela, ou você exibe apenas um endereço da pessoa, ou exibe várias linhas da mesma pessoa com os respectivos endereços. Normalmente há um endereço padrão da pessoa que é exibido nesses casos, mas de qualquer forma, para exibir no datagridview, basta fazer o select com join. Eu faria como o colega Marconcilio falou, uma outra grid para mostrar os endereços.

Comment: você pode editar a pergunta acrescentando mais informações, e pelo seu select, a tabela resultante já contém os dados dos endereços. Se o dgv estiver como autogeneraterows, já deve estar sendo exibido, caso contrário, basta adicionar as colunas desejadas

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

Eu tive o mesmo problema... então resolvi assim:

peguei o JSON retornado da WebApi que no meu caso é assim:

```
{
    "ped_codigo": 1,
    "ped_empresa": 1,
    "emp_razao": "1-EMPRESA",
    "ped_cliente": 2,
    "pes_razao_social": "VICENTE P DOS SANTOS",
    "cid_nome": "TANGUA",
    "uf_descricao": "RIO DE JANEIRO",
    "ped_data_digitacao": "2017-07-12T00:00:00",
    "ped_data_entrega": "2017-07-12T00:00:00",
    "ped_pedido_cliente": "123456",
    "ped_pedido_representante": "12345678",
    "ped_setor": 1,
    "ped_representante": 1,
    "razaoRepresentante": "REPRESENTANTE 1"
}
```

Então simplesmente fiz ele jogar para dentro do DataSource da Grid desta maneira(uso DevExpress):

```
gridControl.DataSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(retorno);
```

Espero que lhe ajude!